# Port and firewall

Tags: firewall

Suppose my institution wants to block all incoming HTTP and HTTPS requests, so firewall is configured for blocking access for incoming request to port 80 and 443, but I can configure some other port for my application for listening for HTTP service, let's say 7001. Then in this case how institution would be able to block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your equipment and software.  For instance, many Cisco devices can use NBAR to do deep packet inspection in order to identify upper layer protocols in use.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the equipment and software. Different vendors have different solutions. NextGen firewalls do this, too. What you are asking is too broad to give you a specific answer. Basically, the inspection of the packets goes beyond the port number to the content of the packets. It may be that an HTTP header is seen in a packet in the stream to identify it as HTTP, and then appropriate action is taken, or not taken, depending on the rules.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, I don't think it could be better explained than this.